# Unknown Publisher warning from self-installing exe after signing with SignTool

Tags: certificate, signtool

I have purchased a code signing certificate for the 3rd time since 2015, but when I convert it to a .pfx file and try to use it to sign a self-extracting installer using the code below, the installer shows the publisher as unknown. This did not happen for any of the previous certificates I have purchased.

```
copy /b 7zS.sfx + config.txt + CaptionPro.7z CaptionPro3.2.153.exe
set FILEDESCR=/s desc "Caption Pro v 3.2.153"
verpatch /va CaptionPro3.2.153.exe %FILEDESCR% 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64\SignTool.exe" sign /f aleka_consulting_pty_ltd_2026.pfx /fd sha1 /p "XXXXXXX" CaptionPro3.2.153.exe
```

If I dump the contents of aleka_consulting_pty_ltd_2026.pfx using

```
certutil -dump aleka_consulting_pty_ltd_2026.pfx
```

at the command line I get the results below, which include the error "Certified public key does not match stored keyset". Is this the cause of my problem, and if so how do I fix it?

```
================ Certificate 0 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 0:
Serial Number: 0ceba62297552e41d68dd86da996151b
Issuer: CN=DigiCert Trusted G4 Code Signing RSA4096 SHA384 2021 CA1, O=DigiCert, Inc., C=US
 NotBefore: 17/10/2023 11:00 AM
 NotAfter: 31/08/2026 10:59 AM
Subject: CN=Aleka Consulting Pty Ltd, O=Aleka Consulting Pty Ltd, L=O'Connor, S=Australian Capital Territory, C=AU
Non-root Certificate
Cert Hash(sha1): ae656c2e258349832111f7e6959cc1e59aa6aead
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
  Provider = Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider

Certificate Public Key:
Version: 3
Public Key Algorithm:
    Algorithm ObjectId: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 RSA
    Algorithm Parameters:
    05 00
Public Key Length: 4096 bits
Public Key: UnusedBits = 0
    0000  30 82 02 0a 02 82 02 01  00 cb a9 87 e0 69 e0 14
    0010  2d 0c 21 95 8f ed ee 49  bf 8d f7 c4 e5 6f c4 f3
    0020  6d 09 ce e8 c1 8c 5c 13  ce 7e ef b7 02 24 b0 8d
    0030  0d 7e a2 0b 97 76 b6 0c  d8 dc 6e 5e 48 57 6f 24
    0040  57 99 8e 27 ee be a9 7f  1b a0 8a 36 15 70 13 70
    0050  86 b4 55 08 f6 74 26 94  c8 63 00 b4 b6 87 08 7b
    0060  3b ff ea 32 d4 69 6c 28  55 63 b2 be c7 24 6e 57
    0070  04 e6 05 e2 6f 12 97 c1  6b 6a 4d de 6e 9a a0 c3
    0080  30 e3 65 8e 96 90 d4 60  cb f7 18 22 e4 bd e8 b6
    0090  fc e5 36 93 6c 16 22 f1  a6 0d e5 98 d0 90 8c a9
    00a0  2e 51 12 90 c3 b3 8f 53  dd 2c 49 49 60 3e 33 a8
    00b0  c5 80 f9 27 32 45 70 35  50 ca a6 9f 80 6b 3f 0c
    00c0  7c 34 3d 28 32 4c 99 f5  47 51 c8 73 c2 52 da 69
    00d0  20 84 93 51 3e 8b b6 db  0c d6 75 d2 8d 81 01 d4
    00e0  69 10 bb 8e 46 87 48 af  ea 73 45 12 b6 3a 67 e5
    00f0  0c cb c0 c9 2f 08 e0 a5  9c 7c b4 bd 55 0d af 57
    0100  4c aa 01 7d 2b 56 01 a9  da f0 2a 5f 97 b6 3d a3
    0110  8c f0 24 2d 26 f7 1d d3  c0 fd e0 e2 17 0a d8 c0
    0120  86 e3 08 2d ce 32 7d ba  53 53 b8 59 2e 17 72 a4
    0130  26 ea 28 df c1 2c 6e 26  06 45 f6 cd 74 0c fa 2f
    0140  bd 31 27 f9 dd 5b 1f 68  3f 16 d0 35 6a 87 95 12
    0150  21 30 35 49 25 34 c0 0a  70 1c d5 de f9 d2 a8 3c
    0160  11 21 fb b2 4d bb 21 59  5d 5f d8 e9 bc 6c 5b 75
    0170  2f ce 39 8d 03 f5 b1 09  e9 80 06 2d fb 8c e6 27
    0180  2f fa d0 29 68 48 22 3f  3c 56 e1 87 18 a1 da 74
    0190  7d 4e 56 d3 df a6 b6 01  4f 3e 17 d3 5f ea 5d 46
    01a0  d7 4f 3c ee 0f d8 19 3c  1e af 11 e0 2c db 72 cc
    01b0  86 12 3d bc e0 cf 61 d1  27 2f fe e4 46 55 cf 8e
    01c0  86 e7 27 5f 6e d2 57 28  9b 3b c3 f5 28 4d 48 ee
    01d0  ef 63 ab e5 d8 22 80 46  8b 15 96 fc 6d 6f b6 53
    01e0  f3 d7 ab f5 c0 69 e6 06  6b 2b c6 c2 ee 03 d8 29
    01f0  ff 43 81 2e 55 83 47 d9  89 c4 81 b7 28 9b a1 02
    0200  8e 9d a6 41 ab 31 30 c4  3b 02 03 01 00 01
Key Id Hash(rfc-sha1): 7f720f3a85fffde2ed1d6094cad75545af374508
Key Id Hash(sha1): 44277b2ff203fe8217478be8f4824c194bd5631d
Key Id Hash(bcrypt-sha1): f473b197c5a785280d6548e0019a3cc04a3100d2
Key Id Hash(bcrypt-sha256): e99db4cb6314e53e90a8c37ffc70c9509dfbb37244933a6a4fb8b429175235ee

Container Public Key:
Public Key Algorithm:
    Algorithm ObjectId: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 RSA
    Algorithm Parameters: NULL
Public Key Length: 2048 bits
Public Key: UnusedBits = 0
    0000  30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01  00 af 0a a0 16 7d ac 52
    0010  d4 08 9b 9f b6 8b 05 2c  fd f2 38 bb 52 95 0c e2
    0020  ec cd 62 53 2f 6b 34 9d  9d 6a b0 e3 44 e7 f1 d4
    0030  59 e4 06 56 50 0f 0c 42  e6 d1 5f 62 6a 6d 04 84
    0040  ac ea e8 91 ea 87 10 56  a3 51 61 1b c3 a0 dc 45
    0050  35 73 8d 73 f2 b9 1e a6  91 f0 3f de c8 c1 a7 f2
    0060  52 7d e3 bd 6a 95 2e 77  80 c3 1b ce f4 80 27 42
    0070  08 f2 8e 4b c7 1c 29 40  49 f7 b8 84 9c 2a 46 3e
    0080  06 5f ee 2a 7a 57 e8 25  ea 10 eb 88 24 3a 38 95
    0090  2e c0 17 a4 42 3d 5c e4  20 ae 0d aa 22 0c 22 98
    00a0  64 c6 ac b5 b2 ee ec fa  f9 d4 10 a2 f5 15 6d 34
    00b0  bb 9e 12 8e 57 52 79 11  1d 1b 08 dd 8d 8d 4b 5d
    00c0  42 fd 46 79 33 b4 b2 a4  d5 bd 97 e8 74 2f 1b 54
    00d0  0f cb d1 ca 6b d1 46 56  8d 87 4a f3 c1 1b a9 36
    00e0  10 fe 6a 19 94 8d 47 33  5a 88 ad 87 18 1e 1d 47
    00f0  ff b1 08 3c c8 a6 91 60  ab 94 03 7c f1 4f 5f c5
    0100  a6 d6 24 37 f5 6a 3a ef  93 02 03 01 00 01
Key Id Hash(rfc-sha1): 71fd56de0a56681a82bc48bb51bc36f5b2f648f9
Key Id Hash(sha1): 212fc0f4b31b616ea1fd06874dcc1f4a1da9d284
Key Id Hash(bcrypt-sha1): 9d66a9751469b816f952acd4011e807bb476e06a
Key Id Hash(bcrypt-sha256): 7f11e8e97d44d550ef304421d5749eadec40df91c3e883441d39ba8b00cbeb2b

ERROR: Certificate public key does NOT match stored keyset
Signature test FAILED
CertUtil: -dump command completed successfully.
```

When I run SignTool in a command window I get:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64\SignTool.exe" sign /f aleka_consulting_pty_ltd_2026.pfx /fd sha1 /p "XXXXXX" CaptionPro3.2.153.exe
Done Adding Additional Store
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to load the signing
        certificate from: C:\Installs Caption Pro\CaptionPro3.2.153.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I'd forgotten I had to use a Digicert Token for signing. The signing process is quite separate from making the self extracting .exe. It uses a utility from Digicert.